# Derivative of $x(\ln a^x)$

Tags: derivatives

I know that you should take the derivative of $x \ln (a^x)$ by the product rule to get

$$x\ln a + \ln a^x= 2x \ln a$$

But whenever I see $x\ln (a^x)$ I want to bring the exponent down and in this case create $x^2 \ln a$ which would generate the differential $2x\ln a$.

I am confused why I cannot do this.  Can someone explain?

Thanks
Mazin

Comment: Just notice that $x\ln a+\ln a^x=2x\ln a$ (or $2\ln a^x$, or $x\ln a^2$ or $\ln a^{2x}$).

Comment: I don't understand the question. You *can* do this.

Answer (score 2):

$$x\ln a+\ln a^x=2x \ln a$$

You can bring down the exponenent.